# How to find a unitary lift $V \in B(H)$ such that $\pi(V)=u)$ given that $\delta_{1}\left([u]_{1}\right)=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, homological-algebra, c-star-algebras, k-theory

The problem about K-theory is from Rørdam's book [*An Introduction to K-theory for $C^*$-algebras*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiwl4SmsKL4AhW1RfEDHQAdClAQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2FAn_Introduction_to_K_Theory_for_C_Algebr.html%3Fid%3DSMiB8VIB5UIC&usg=AOvVaw3YJTtVr68ofcp61jRUPF4V) Exercise 9.6.

> Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. Consider
> the short exact sequence $$ 0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{K}
>  \stackrel{\iota}{\longrightarrow} B(H) \stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow}
>  \mathcal{Q}(H) \longrightarrow 0, $$ and let $\delta_{1}:
>  K_{1}(\mathcal{Q}(H)) \rightarrow K_{0}(\mathcal{K})$ be its associated index map.
>
> (i) Let $E, F$ be projections in $B(H)$ such
> that $\operatorname{dim}(E(H)) \leqslant \operatorname{dim}(F(H))$.
> Show that there exists a partial isometry $V$ in $B(H)$ satisfying
> $V^{*} V=E$ and $V V^{*} \leqslant F$.
>
> (ii) Let $u$ be a unitary
> element in $\mathcal{Q}(H)$. Show that there is $S$ in $B(H)$ such
> that $\pi(S)=u$ and such that $S$ is either an isometry, i.e., $S^{*} S=I$, or a co-isometry, i.e., $S S^{*}=I$.
>
> (iii) Let again $u$ be a
> unitary element in $\mathcal{Q}(H)$. Show that $u$ lifts to a unitary
> operator in $B(H)$ (i.e., there is a unitary operator $V$ on $H$ such
> that $\pi(V)=u)$ if and only if $\delta_{1}\left([u]_{1}\right)=0$.
>
> (Here $\mathcal{K}$ is the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators in $B(H)$ and $\mathcal{Q}(H)) = B(H)/\mathcal{K}$ is the Calkin algebra, and $\delta_1$ is the index map connecting the $K_1$ and $K_0$ group.)

I have done the first two of them. The problem I face is the other half of (iii) where I have no idea of how to find a unitary lift $V \in B(H)$ such that $\pi(V)=u)$ given that $\delta_{1}\left([u]_{1}\right)=0$.

Any help is apprecited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (b) to find an isometry/co-isometry $S$ mapping to $u$. Then $S$ is a Fredholm operator whose index equals $\delta([u]_1)$, once $K_0(\mathcal K)$ is identified with $\mathbb Z$.

Letting $E=1-S^*S$, and $F=1-SS^*$, we then have that $E$ and $F$ are projections of finite rank  and
$$
0=\delta([u]_1)=\text{ind}(S)=$$$$=\text{rank}(F)-\text{rank}(E),
$$
so $E$ and $F$ have the same rank.

Since either $E$ of $F$ is zero we deduce that both are zero, and hence that $S$ is unitary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do you see that $E$ and $F$ are of the same rank? If $E$ and $F$ are defined as these, then one of them are zero, hence both of the ranks are zero as you said. This leads to nothing.

Comment: Sorry.  The proof is much easier!  See the last edit.

Comment: Both projections have same rank since the rank difference is the index, which is assumed to be zero.

Comment: How to see that 1-SS* is of finite rank?

Comment: $\pi(1-SS^*)=1-uu^*=0$, because $u$ is unitary.  Therefore $1-SS^*$ is a compact projection and so necessarily of finite rank.

Comment: Thank you. One final question: how to see that the index of S is indeed rankF - rankE? I am not so familiar with the concept of the indices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136982/discussion-between-scienceage-and-ruy).